# Entity Framework Reusing Connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

in a using block for a connection to the entities,

How am I to reuse the connection when calling another method?

so I have:

```
using (SampleEntities entities = new SampleEntities()) {
    entities.Connection.Open();
    SomeMethod();

    ...
}


void SomeMethod() {
   using (SampleEntities entities = new SampleEntities())
   {
      // I want to be able to use the existing connection before the method call, any ideas?
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not have

```
 void SomeMethod(SampleEnities context)
```

and pass it in; let the first "using" sort out disposal.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `ConnectionScope` and `DataContextScope` using the documents here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300805.aspx

This means you can do this:

```
using (var connection = container.Resolve<IDbConnection>())
using (var context = container.Resolve<IMyDataContext>())
{
    context.Connection = connection;

    // Do some stuff...

    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

This is what I've done, and it works a **treat**!  It means that the `context.SubmitChanges()` is only called at the top of the stack.  Therefore allowing you to call methods that use connection/context without worrying about passing them in as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you are using the same connection string, the connection pool is handled for you.

Even though you are using dispose, it doesn't close the connection.  It returns it to the pool for next use.

For transaction scope, you want to use the same connection, so you have to do everything in the transaction before that connection is disposed.

so:

```
using(...){
  call methods execute transaction...

 You can pass the connection into other methods here for use, 
 just make sure it doesn't get disposed in that method.

 commit..
}//connection is disposed.
```

Comment: I am using the same connection string. If I have a transaction scope, I do not want to elevate to MSDTC so therefore, I want to be able to reuse the existing connection.

Comment: When using Database-first, Entity Framework thinks all the connections are different, so existing database connections are not reused.

Answer (score 0):

```
void SomeMethod(SampleEntities entities){

  var do_dispose = false;

  try{

  if(entities == null) { entities = new SampleEntities();
  entities.Connection.Open(); 
  do_dispose = true; }


    // do with entity object...
  }
  finally{
    if(do_dispose && entities != null){
      entities.Dispose();
    }
  }

}
```

usage:

```
using(SampleEntities entities = new SampleEntities()){
  entites.Connection.Open();
  SomeMethod(entities);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An overload of `DbContext` constructor allows to determine whether an existing connection should be disposed as context gets disposed or not. You need to pass a `DbConnection` to the context and ask it to keep the connection alive:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
  using(var context1 = new SampleEntities(existingConnection:con, contextOwnsConnection:false)
  {
  }

  using(var context2 = new SampleEntities(existingConnection:con, contextOwnsConnection:false)
  {
  }
}
```

Change the context to pass the params to the base :

```
class SampleEntities : DbContext
{
    public SampleEntities(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection) :
                base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection) )
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: When using the EDMX designer, the templates used to generate the context classes do not include an overload to specify whether or not the context owns the connection: the _only_ constructor accepting an existing connection specifies that the context owns it (EF 6).